# View the change history of a certain file using github.dev

Tags: github

Code editor github.com provides is great for me.  It makes my coding life much easier.
You can check it my pressing "." key in any repository page of your github.com page.
The only problem I'm facing is I **can't see file's change history**.
So I always open two web pages for one project, github.dev and github.com.
I use github.dev for commit(it's very convenient to double check my modification on the file than in github.com), and use github.com for the old changes.
Is there any **menu or command or editor plugin** that I can see the old history of file in github.dev directly, so I can avoid referencing two web pages.

[image]

[image]